# Calling interface method in fragment throws ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, fragment

This is the problematic line in my code:

```
listAdapter.setCustomButtonListener((CustomButtonListener) getActivity());**
```

This listener works perfectly inside the `AppCompatActivity` but when I try to use it inside a fragment it throws a `ClassCastException`. This is the logcat:

**Logcat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process: info.tranetech.laundry, PID: 21707
                                                                        java.lang.ClassCastException: info.tranetech.laundry.pricelist.ItemListTab cannot be cast to tranetech.laundry.pricelist.CustomButtonListener
                                                                            at info.tranetech.laundry.pricelist.ManItems$GetContacts.onPostExecute(ManItems.java:177)
                                                                            at info.tranetech.laundry.pricelist.ManItems$GetContacts.onPostExecute(ManItems.java:98)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5748)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my interface

**CustomButtonListener.java**

```
public interface CustomButtonListener {
    public void onButtonClickListener(int position, EditText editText, int value);
}
```

This is My TabBar (AppCompatActivity)

**ItemListTab.java**

```
public class ItemListTab extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_call,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_list_tabs);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new ManItems(), "");
        adapter.addFrag(new WomanItems(), "");
        adapter.addFrag(new KidItems(), "");
        adapter.addFrag(new HouseHoldItems(), "");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Fragment where i call the

listAdapter.setCustomButtonListener((CustomButtonListener) getActivity());

**ManItems.java**

```
   public class ManItems extends Fragment implements CustomButtonListener{

    private ListView listView;
    View rootView;
    Context context;
    private ListAdapter listAdapter;
    public static String[] ItemName, prices,ItemImage;
    Button PlaceOrder;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    HashMap<String, String> itemMap;
    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ItemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    public ManItems() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.customListView);
        PlaceOrder = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.place_order);

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();


        PlaceOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (ListAdapter.map.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please select items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    ListAdapter.map.values().removeAll(Collections.singleton("0"));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OrderList.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        return  rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClickListener(int position, EditText editText, int value) {
        //  View view = listView.getChildAt(position);
        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());

        quantity = quantity + 1 * value;
        if (quantity < 0)
            quantity = 0;
        editText.setText(quantity + "");

    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            JSONParser JP = new JSONParser();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = JP.makeServiceCall("http://openspace.tranetech.com/mis/Laundry/items.php", JSONParser.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray itmeArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Data");

                    ItemName = new String[itmeArray.length()];
                    prices = new String[itmeArray.length()];
                    ItemImage = new String[itmeArray.length()];

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < itmeArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject item = itmeArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String price = item.getString("price").toString();
                        String name = item.getString("item_name").toString();
                        String image = item.getString("image").toString();

                        ItemName[i] = name;
                        prices[i] = price;
                        ItemImage[i] =image;

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {

                for (int z = 0; z < ItemName.length; z++) {

                    Log.d("Name  ", "" + ItemName[z]);
                    Log.d("Price ", "" + prices[z]);
                    Log.d("Images ", "" + ItemImage[z]);
                }
                pDialog.dismiss();

            }
//            images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.ProductImages);

            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            listAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), ItemName, ItemImage, prices);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            listAdapter.setCustomButtonListener((CustomButtonListener) getActivity());

        }
    }


}
```

After change this **listAdapter.setCustomButtonListener(ManItems.this);**

**Logcat**

```
     java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at info.tranetech.laundry.pricelist.ListAdapter.getView(ListAdapter.java:95)
                                                                            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2768)
                                                                            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1817)
                                                                            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:703)
                                                                            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:769)
                                                                            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1647)
                                                                            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2586)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15903)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4932)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1692)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1534)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1443)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15903)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4932)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1627)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15903)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4932)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1034)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:744)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1180)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:757)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15903)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4932)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15903)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4932)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1692)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1534)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1443)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15903)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4932)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15903)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4932)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1692)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1534)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1443)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15903)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4932)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15903)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4932)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2133)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1297)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6773)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5748)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)

  [1]: https://www.vlemonn.com/Blog/Android/Android-Custom-ListView-with-ImageView-EditText-and-Button/
```

**Error Location**

```
for (int z = 0; z < MainActivity_items.ItemImage.length; z++) {

            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(""+MainActivity_items.ItemImage[position])
                    .into(listViewHolder.ivProduct);
        }
```

**ListAdapter.java**

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public ArrayList<Integer> quantity = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public ArrayList<Integer> price = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private String[] listViewItems, prices, static_price;
    String[] images;
    View row = null;

    static String get_price, get_quntity;
    int g_quntity, g_price, g_minus;

    private Context context;
    CustomButtonListener customButtonListener;

    static HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();


    public ListAdapter(Context context, String[] listViewItems, String[] images, String[] prices) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listViewItems = listViewItems;
        this.images = images;
        this.prices = prices;

        for (int i = 0; i < listViewItems.length; i++) {
            quantity.add(0);
        }
    }

    public void setCustomButtonListener(CustomButtonListener customButtonListner) {
        this.customButtonListener = customButtonListner;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listViewItems.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return listViewItems[position];
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ListViewHolder listViewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_listview, parent, false);
            listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
            listViewHolder.tvProductName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
            listViewHolder.ivProduct = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivproduct);
            listViewHolder.tvPrices = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvProductPrice);
            listViewHolder.btnPlus = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.ib_addnew);
            listViewHolder.edTextQuantity = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editTextQuantity);
            listViewHolder.btnMinus = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.ib_remove);
            static_price = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Price);
            row.setTag(listViewHolder);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
            listViewHolder = (ListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //Loading image from below url into imageView

for (int z = 0; z < MainActivity_items.ItemImage.length; z++) {
    Picasso.with(context)
           .load(""+MainActivity_items.ItemImage[position])
           .into(listViewHolder.ivProduct);
}

//      listViewHolder.ivProduct.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(position, -1));
        listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.setText(quantity.get(position) + "");
        listViewHolder.tvProductName.setText(listViewItems[position]);
        listViewHolder.tvPrices.setText(prices[position]);


        listViewHolder.btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (customButtonListener != null) {
                    customButtonListener.onButtonClickListener(position, listViewHolder.edTextQuantity, 1);

                    quantity.set(position, quantity.get(position) + 1);
                    //price.set(position, price.get(position) + 1);

                    row.getTag(position);

                    get_price = listViewHolder.tvPrices.getText().toString();

                    g_price = Integer.valueOf(static_price[position]);

                    get_quntity = listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.getText().toString();
                    g_quntity = Integer.valueOf(get_quntity);

                    Integer.parseInt(listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.getText().toString());
                    map.put("" + listViewHolder.tvProductName.getText().toString(), Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.getText().toString())));
//                    Log.d("A ", "" + a);
//                    Toast.makeText(context, "A" + a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    Log.d("Position ", "" + position);
//                    System.out.println(+position + " Values " + map.values());
                    listViewHolder.tvPrices.getTag();
                    listViewHolder.tvPrices.setText("" + g_price * g_quntity);
                    ShowHashMapValue();

                }


            }

        });
        listViewHolder.btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (customButtonListener != null) {

                    customButtonListener.onButtonClickListener(position, listViewHolder.edTextQuantity, -1);
                    if (quantity.get(position) > 0)
                        quantity.set(position, quantity.get(position) - 1);

                    get_price = listViewHolder.tvPrices.getText().toString();
                    g_minus = Integer.valueOf(get_price);
                    g_price = Integer.valueOf(static_price[position]);
                    int minus = g_minus - g_price;
                    if (minus >= g_price) {
                        listViewHolder.tvPrices.setText("" + minus);
                    }
                    map.put("" + listViewHolder.tvProductName.getText().toString(), Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.getText().toString())));
                    ShowHashMapValue();
                }
            }
        });


        return row;
    }

    private void ShowHashMapValue() {
        /**
         * get the Set Of keys from HashMap
         */
        Set setOfKeys = map.keySet();

/**
 * get the Iterator instance from Set
 */
        Iterator iterator = setOfKeys.iterator();

/**
 * Loop the iterator until we reach the last element of the HashMap
 */
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
/**
 * next() method returns the next key from Iterator instance.
 * return type of next() method is Object so we need to do DownCasting to String
 */
            String key = (String) iterator.next();

/**
 * once we know the 'key', we can get the value from the HashMap
 * by calling get() method
 */
            int value = map.get(key);

            System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This error raised because your activity does not implement the interface. Activity should implement the interface if you want the callback handle by the activity. In your case, by changing listAdapter.setCustomButtonListener((CustomButtonListener) getActivity()); to listAdapter.setCustomButtonListener(ManItems.this) will solve your problem as I notice your fragment has implemented the interface and i assume it's the fragment that handles the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, the `ItemListTab` activity cannot be cast to a `CustomButtonListener` because it does not implement it, **the current fragment** does. So you need to change

```
listAdapter.setCustomButtonListener((CustomButtonListener) getActivity());
```

to

```
listAdapter.setCustomButtonListener(ManItems.this);
/* Not listAdapter.setCustomButtonListener(this), otherwise
 you would be referring to the AsyncTask 'GetContacts' itself */
```

Comment: Thanks for reply That means i am can not implement in fragment??

Comment: Of course you can, just change the line above as I said & you would be good to go.

Comment: Actually @ArpitPatel , your question's problem is technically solved. The problem you have now has nothing to do with the actual question. Plus, I can't tell from the logcat what the error is nor how to fix it. So you gonna have to ask a new question about it, & make sure that you only post code that is relevant to the issue, so that the community could help you better.

Comment: found error in getView() replace MainActivity_items = ManItem and appreciate your help you made my day

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you
For using interface listener in fragment
don't implement on fragment class , implement Listener in Tab Activity
And image View or any content of fragment should be public static

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity ItemListTab must implement CustomButtonListener if you are using getActivity()

Pass reference of ManItems because ManItems implemented CustomButtonListener